# Make a table scrollable with html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll, overflow

I made a DashBoard and in my mailPage I can't make it scrollable.

I upload my website if you have time to check my problem.

My Code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var deleteSVG = '<svg class="deleteSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20.2871 5.24297C20.6761 5.24297 21 5.56596 21 5.97696V6.35696C21 6.75795 20.6761 7.09095 20.2871 7.09095H3.71385C3.32386 7.09095 3 6.75795 3 6.35696V5.97696C3 5.56596 3.32386 5.24297 3.71385 5.24297H6.62957C7.22185 5.24297 7.7373 4.82197 7.87054 4.22798L8.02323 3.54598C8.26054 2.61699 9.0415 2 9.93527 2H14.0647C14.9488 2 15.7385 2.61699 15.967 3.49699L16.1304 4.22698C16.2627 4.82197 16.7781 5.24297 17.3714 5.24297H20.2871ZM18.8058 19.134C19.1102 16.2971 19.6432 9.55712 19.6432 9.48913C19.6626 9.28313 19.5955 9.08813 19.4623 8.93113C19.3193 8.78413 19.1384 8.69713 18.9391 8.69713H5.06852C4.86818 8.69713 4.67756 8.78413 4.54529 8.93113C4.41108 9.08813 4.34494 9.28313 4.35467 9.48913C4.35646 9.50162 4.37558 9.73903 4.40755 10.1359C4.54958 11.8992 4.94517 16.8102 5.20079 19.134C5.38168 20.846 6.50498 21.922 8.13206 21.961C9.38763 21.99 10.6811 22 12.0038 22C13.2496 22 14.5149 21.99 15.8094 21.961C17.4929 21.932 18.6152 20.875 18.8058 19.134Z" fill="#200E32"/></svg>'
    nbMail = 100;

    for (i = 0; i < nbMail; i++) {
        document.getElementById("mailTableBody").innerHTML += '<tr class="mail mail' + i + '"><td class="mailSender">toto@toto.com</td><td class="mailObject">toto object</td><td class="mailFirstCaracters">Hello World !</td><td class="mailDate">Monday 30 december 2033 11:22PM</td><td>' + deleteSVG + '</td></tr>';
    }
});
```

```css
html{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mailTableBody{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 67%;
}
.mail {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
    margin-top: 2%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}

.deleteSVG{
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page mailPage" id="mailPage">
        <table class="mailTable">
            <tbody class="mailTableBody" id="mailTableBody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot.

https://edtmimi.000webhostapp.com/dashBoard/

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `overflow : hidden` property of the `html` class, in your `.mailPage` page like so :

```
.mailPage .page {
    
    /* added below line */
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: it's probably because you're setting the `overflow : hidden` option on your `html`

Comment: I don't understand because in my other page note I overriding and its working :(